# Getting Lets encrypt certificates for subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl-certificate, https, lets-encrypt

I have several servers under domain `myorg.example.com`. For example `git.myorg.example.com`.
I am planning to start using  certificates provided by Lets Encrypt for these servers.

Most of these servers are for internal use only and I don't like opening port 80 to internet for using HTTP-01 challenge. My DNS provider does not support DNS-01 challenge and switching to new provider is not possible right now.

I am wondering if following setup is possible:

- Creating server at domain `myorg.example.com` and opening its port port 80 to internet.
- Using `myorg.example.com` as centralised certificate server and doing all certificate generation there and pushing new certs and keys to other servers using script.

  - Can I get Lets Encrypt certificate for `git.myorg.example.com` using `myorg.example.com`?
    Is control of upper level domain enough proof for getting certificate for subdomain?

Comment: No, it is not.  You can, however, use a DNS challenge where the challenge record is a `CNAME` to another domain (including a subdomain of your existing domain).  The target of the `CNAME` can be with a DNS provider that does support challenges.

Comment: Why is a wildcard cert not a good solution (`*.example.com` or `*.myorg.example.com`)? It's not that hard with `certbot`.

Comment: @bitinerant You need to use DNS challenge to get a wildcard certificate, AFAIK

Comment: I will look into using `CNAME` like suggested.